# Git: create copy of (historic) remote read-only tag

Tags: git, history, tags, local

Here's the deal:

A Github repo features a historical import from CVS, divided in tags of previous releases. I would like to locally build the various releases to document the UI changes (need screenshots for a writeup).

So there is absolutely no need for tracking / further development on the tagged release.

**I just want the specific files from a specific tag in a fresh directory so I can install that version.**

My Git version is 1.6.0.4

Thanks!

Comment: Given that git is based on diffs from previous revisions, I don't see how you can just pull the head of those branches without pulling their whole history. Why can't you just do a full checkout, copy the directory to a different folder, then switch back to the branch you were working on?

Comment: Perhaps I am misunderstanding Git? I just want the files like they were in, lets say,2005 - I do not need any history. It's okay if it is there though. Github itself allows downloading them as zip packages so I could do that, but since there are rather a lot of 'release-branches' in there its easier to just pull them in from the commandline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you clone directly the right branch?

```
git clone -b releaseXbranch url_remote_repo localbarerepo_releaseX
cd releaseX
```

And then update it to the right point in time you want to see for that release (see [`git-rev-parse` syntax](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-rev-parse.html)):

```
git checkout @{2005-01-01 00:00:00} # state of that branch in 2005
```